# Can dogs get bored of a walk?

Tags: dogs, psychology, exercise, mental-stimulation, puppy

I take my four-month-old puppy on about three walks per day. The walks are almost always a 15-20 minute loop starting at my house. It goes through several neighborhoods, a park, and on a waterfront trail. It's a convenient, quiet, scenic, and easy walk. Because of this, about 85% of the walks per week are this walk, or a slight variation (such as an extension or short-cut).  My dog and I also sometimes drive to a beach or trail, but because of COVID 19, this is less frequent.

My dog seems to enjoy the walk in question, but I want to make sure:

Can/do dogs get bored of a walk?

Comment: I would guess, that it depends to some degree of the dog's character. But in general I would assume, that dogs like to walk in the area, they are used to. Like a wolf, which would have some "own" area. As long as your dog enjoys the walks, is interested in sniffing and exploring, the same way every day should not be a problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to cite any sources, the general answer is **no**.

I've heard that many dogs **enjoy walking the same path** every day, because

- It gives them a routine and they know what to expect. Especially anxious dogs feel safer when they can predict what's going to happen.
- Dogs have much more sensory input than humans. For example, they smell who was there since the last time. That makes the same old path less boring for them.
- Wild dogs would patrol the borders of their territory in regular intervals. Taking the same walk every day might feel like that for your dog.

That being said, there's also **nothing wrong with changing routes** and exploring new paths every day. You just don't have to if you don't want to.